# How make a multi language routes, with rewrite rules or rewrite endpoints?

Tags: url-rewriting, multi-language, rewrite-rules, routing, endpoints

I want to know a concept of making a multi language routing system for WP. That is the best practice, to make this routing system with `add_rewrite_rules` for pages post archive etc in part, or to use `add_rewrite_endpoint` with bitmask?